# How to find occurrences of the largest integer in C without array?

Tags: c, if-statement, count, integer

In my code, I was able to find the largest integer within a set of numbers that ask to be inputted. I was not able to find the number of occurrences my largest integer was inputted. I feel like my problem is with the "if and else" statements. 
For example, when the first if statement is satisfied, I think it increments the "count" once and skips over all the other "if and else" statements and executes the last print function. So the count always ends up as `2`.

What can I do to have the `count` count the number of occurrences of the largest integer?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int count;
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    count = 1;

printf("Enter 5 integers within 1-10:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e);


if (e >= a 
 && e >= b 
 && e >= c 
 && e >= d){
    printf ("Largest integer is %d\n", e);
    count++;
    }

else if (d >= a 
      && d >= b 
      && d >= c 
      && d >= e){
    printf ("Largest integer is %d\n", d);
    count++;

    }

else if (c >= a 
      && c >= b 
      && c >= d 
      && c >= e){
    printf ("Largest integer is %d\n", c);
    count++;
    }

else if (b >= a 
      && b >= c 
      && b >= d 
      && b >= e){
    printf ("Largest integer is %d\n", b);
    count++;
    }

else {
    printf ("Largest is %d\n", a);
    count++;
    }       

printf ("Largest integer occurred %d times.\n", count);
system ("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: also using the bcc52 compiler.

Comment: mayb3 `count = 0` and a while loops

Comment: You only need the largest value, but you are attempting to **sort** all 5 values. What's the point of that? Simply use an additional variable, take two values, compare them, store the larger one, and proceed to the next value.

Comment: When i set     count = 0, my count at the end ends up as 1 if i input 3 of the same "largest integer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things. Instead of five variables, you could have just one, and input to it in a loop, saving the maximum and the count as you go:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_VARS 5

int i;
int input;
int curr_max = INT_MIN;
int count = 0;

for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_VARS; ++i) {
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    if (input > curr_max) {
        curr_max = input;
        count = 1;
    } else if (input == curr_max) {
        ++count;
    }
}

printf ("Largest integer is %d, appearing %d times\n", curr_max, count);
```

Comment: for declaring the `int curr_max = INT_MIN;` how do I assign the INT_MIN to be my minimum integer?

Comment: @AaronNam The `INT_MIN` constant should be provided by `<limits.h>`. Alternatively, just use -32768.

Comment: For future references, when I have 50 integers to put in, do I `#define NUMBER_OF_VARS 50`?
Also, I'm a little confused about the if and else statement you have in your code. 
Since you have a loop that ends when the `NUMBER_OF_VARS=5`, does that allow the user to input 5 integers?

Comment: @AaronNam yes, exactly!

Comment: oh wow, i see what you did on your first `if` statement. It's looping itself until it reaches the largest integer. And when it does reach the largest your `else if` statement adds the `count` for however much it was inputted.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need 5 vars, then Mureinik has the answer. If you you have to have the 5 variables that I'd do it like this:

```
int max = -9999;
if (a > max) {
    max = a;
}
if (b > max) {
   max = b;
}
/* repeat for c d and e */
```

Comment: Or `int max = a;`, and skip the first `if`... then it'd still work if all the numbers are less than `-9999`...

Comment: @Dmitri - 100% correct - you can see I assumed positive ints ;-)